# Docker ubuntu não starta

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Prezados criei um container ubuntu segue a prova:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E depois efetuei o start no container

[image: Docker start]

Note que acima não possue nenhum erro, mas o container não roda, conforme imagem abaixo

[image: docker sem nada]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver basicamente desinstalei segundo a documentação do fedora.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/fedora/#uninstall-docker

Depois rodei o seguinte comando

```
sudo pkcon refresh force -c -1
```

E reinstalei
 https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/fedora/#install-docker-ce

Agora sem rodar o comando

```
sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled docker-ce-edge
```

usando apenas a versão estavel

Comment: Não precisava reinstalar. O CMD do seu container é /bin/bash, assim você precisa rodar com -it para funcionar assumir o terminal.

Isso acontece quando você executa um docker run e após o parâmetro *nome da imagem*, você define /bin/bash ou quando você não determina nenhum CMD no caso de um build seu.

Comment: Então basicamente teria que rodar o ubuntu com  um bash   (  ```docker run -it ubuntu bash```) ?